# News database design

Tags: sql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I am making a news website but I want to let the user insert statuses from Facebook. The user can put the status anywhere in the news while writing it.  I want to display the news as it's inserted.

Here's an example of news' content

> "Some user inserted text *Status* Some other text *Some other status* another text *Another Status*"

So I'm thinking what is a good database design in that case. The status has user, who has wrote it, date and content. The news has title, description and date.

I've come up with five tables.

Table **NewsHeader**

```
id  
NewsTitle  
NewsDesc  
NewsDate
User
```

Table **NewsContent** - contains only id and the message from the status or  text of the news

```
id  
content
```

Table **NewsContentDetails** - contains details of the status

```
id
ContentUser
ContentDate
```

Table **NewsContentDetailsLink** -  junction table of **NewsContent** and **NewsContentDetails**

```
NewsContentId  
NewsContentDetailsId
```

Table **NewsHeaderContent** - junction table of **NewsHeader** and **NewsContent**

```
NewsHeaderId  
NewsContentId
```

Is that a good database design or is there's a better way to do it? I'm concerned that I'll have to write many JOINs in the sql query when displaying the news and that will be slow.

**EDIT:**
The DB design suggested by @hrr

> ```
> **News:**
> ```
>
> ID | Title | Content | User | Date
>
> ```
> **Elements:**
> ```
>
> ID | Content | User | Date | News_ID

But some fields in **elements** will be empty and I think that this's not a good option.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Honestly the biggest problem I see is the names seems very generic.  I can't even understand how you're trying to model things.  Names should be descriptive, and these just aren't.  I would prefer `[NewsArticleHeader]`, `[NewsArticleContent]`, etc.  I also prefer to organize tables loosely with their name.  Here it's obvious from just the name that `[NewsArticleHeader]` and `[NewsArticleContent]` relate.  Terse object names save time typing while coding, but waste time later by confusing those who read the code or work with the DB schema.  Typing is easy.  Understanding is hard.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it's better now.

Comment: What will make the Status special and different from the whole text? Why not merging down and you just have a nvarchar(max) field?

Comment: Some other values are inserted with the status - such as date, user who has written the status, picture of the user and etc.

Comment: Will the content of the news or the status change after they have been used to create a sentence of form (news status news status...) or will it remain same and the user cannot alter it?

Comment: The user can edit the text of the news but can't edit the text of the status. He can only delete the status.

Comment: You need to then optimize for reads, I have added my answer considering this. I have provided a news-message mapper table to accommodate updating the news

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need NewsHeaderContent unless you want to use the same content in more than one header, but I don't believe you want it, so you can use two tables:

Table **NewsHeader**

```
id  
NewsTitle  
NewsDesc  
NewsDate
```

Table **NewsContent**

```
NewsId
ContentId  
Sequence
content
ContentUser
ContentDate
```

you can use the field `Sequence` to order the content.

An example of some data in this structure:

**NewsHeader**

```
id    NewsTitle       NewsDesc               NewsDate
 1    'First News'    'Some Description'     2012-10-07
 2    'Another News'  'Description of News'  2102-12-07
```

**NewsContent**

```
NewsId  ContentId   Sequence  content                    ContentUser  ContentDate
     1          1          1  'Some Text'                       NULL      NULL
     2          1          1  'Some user inserted text'         NULL      NULL
     2          2          2  [Status]                         User2  2012-12-07
     2          3          4  [Some other status]              User2  2012-12-07
     2          4          3  'Some other text'                 NULL      NULL
     2          5          5  'another text'                    NULL      NULL
     2          6          6  [Another Status]                 User2  2012-12-07
```

The sequence would be able to be changed, and as ContentUser and ContentDate would only be used when it's a status, then you could use these field to indentify it text or status, or you can add a filed `Type` that could hold for example `T` for text and `S` for status.

Here a SQLFiddle of my example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2531/2/0)

Comment: ContentDate on the statuses must be the statuses' date. And ContentUser is the statuses' user so these two will be empty unless I'm inserting statuses' information.

Comment: You can allow ContentUser and ContentDate be nullable if that's the case, I will edit my anwser to reflect this, and improve the NewsContent to allow futures changes.

Comment: I have doubts about these empty fields as they're going to be much. Is this against normalization rules?

Comment: @lam3r4370  Is this against normalization rules? none that I know, a NULL value is the absence of data, and that is exactly the case here.

Comment: Why's the ContentId table and is the Sequence table necessary?

Comment: ContendId is part of the Primary key together with NewsID, the Sequence is to allow the ordering of the contents independently of the order they are saved. I put a SQLFiddle of my example to be easy to see the structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one table for News and one table for Elements.

**News:**

```
ID | Title | Content | User | Date
```

**Elements:**

```
ID | Content | User | Date | News_ID
```

Every element will have its own news id! No need for creating extra 'junction' tables.

Comment: But the user can insert the status wherever he wants in the news and I want to display it as he inserted it.

Comment: Can you try to explain further? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Here's the content of a piece of news "Some user inserted text **Status** Some other text **Some other status** another text **Another Status**". So I can't figure it out how I can save the text sequence with your database design

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want the read operation to extremely quick (which I assume would be given the assumption it is a news site), possibly the following design would hold good:

Overall table design:
[image]

1. I do not see a reason to separate News content and news header? So I am assuming it is one-one mapping (even if this is not the case the solution does not change a lot). So I would simply have a News table

   > News
   >       id | Title | Desc | Date | Content
2. Next I would have a UserStatus table

   > UserStatus
   >       id | User Id | Status Text

When the user wants to create a news message such as the one pointed out by you ["Some user inserted text Status Some other text Some other status another text Another Status" ], he/she can simply select the news and/or status for each fragment of the sentence.

After the user creates a sentence you can fetch the related content news and status ans store the formed message in a table directly, so you would have a message table which is optimized for read:

```
Message
id | message | User id | DateTime
```

The disadvantage is you can filter by status or news id nor you can update the message if either of news or status change.


*An alternative if we assume that you allowing the user to change either news or status or you want filter messages by news id or status id is:*

Store a mapping of news ids, and message ids in which the news has been referenced and a mapping of status ids, and message ids in which the status has been referenced along with the  fragment sequence number. So you would have:

```
News-Message-Mapper
News Id | Message Id | Fragment Sequence
```

and

```
Status-Message-Mapper
Status Id | Message Id | Fragment Sequence
```

Fragment sequence indicates the position where the status or the message appears in the overall message.

Now if a news or status is updated or deleted you would simply refer to both the mapping tables and either re-generate those messages or delete them.

This optimizes the reads, but the updates are complicated, but your referential integrity and normalization rules are maintained. Plus you can filter the messages by news id or status id

Comment: Ok but what if the user reorders the position of the statuses?

Comment: Then you need to change the Fragment sequences in News-Message mapper and Status-message mapper or better just delete the old mappings in both the tables and add news entries based on the re-ordered message.

Comment: Yes that is correct. So this would makes reads very simple and fast, you do not have to perform any joins